# Using jquery ajax post to pass array to controller fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an input form, which is rendered using model similar to this. I have tried to simplify the example for clarity.

```
[Serializable]
public class OrderDetailsModel
{ 
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public Address[] OrderAddresses { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Address
{ 
    public string BuildingNameNumber { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

It is rendered using Razor markup similar to this

```
<form id="orderForm">
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname)
    </div>


    @for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var addressDisplayDivId = $"addressDisplay{i}";

        <div id="@addressDisplayDivId">
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderAddresses[i].BuildingNameNumber)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderAddresses[i].BuildingNameNumber, new {@id = $"buildingNameNumber{i}"})
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderAddresses[i].Town)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderAddresses[i].Town, new {@id = $"town{i}"})
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderAddresses[i].Postcode)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderAddresses[i].Postcode, new {@id = $"postcode{i}"})
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <a href="/MyController/ActionMethod" id="submit">Submit</a>
</form>
```

I am attempting to post the form using jQuery ajax

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var submitUrl = $("#submit").attr("href");
     var model = $("#orderForm").serialize();
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: submitUrl,
         data: model,
         success: function(result) {
             alert("Success");
         },
         error: function(result) {
             alert("Error");
         }
     });
 });
```

To a controller action

```
public MyController
 {
     public ActionResult ActionMethod(OrderDetailsModel model)
     {
     }
 }
```

The problem is my action is not being called. If i remove the Address[] it works ok, but introducing that complexity in the model seems to prevent the post to the action from working.

The problem seems to lie in the jquery serialize and how it constructs the Address array before posting to the action.

Can anyone suggest a way of dealing with this?

Comment: This code works fine for me when I tested it. I guess you are missing some important detail which is making the difference.

Comment: do you get an exception anywhere? Does the call drop into the "error" callback? What does the network tab show as the response to the ajax call?

Comment: `href="/My/ActionMethod"` - delete 'Controller' - and I assume its really `public class MyController : Controller`

Comment: I am getting a Success alert, but it does not seem to invoke the controller action. No logs are coming from the method, and no breakpoints are hit. I'm trying to simplify my version down to the above version and see if I can find a difference. So far, no luck

Has anyone managed to invoke the controller action? Or are you just seeing the success alert?

Comment: have a look at the network tab then and check a) it's hitting the URL you think it should be, and b) what the request and response look like for the ajax call. If you're getting a Success alert it must be hitting _something_. What's the contents of `result` when it comes back? Is it what you expect? (`console.log(JSON.stringify(result));'` will log it for you)

Comment: Thanks @ADyson. Looked in the console, and spotted there was actually there was nothing in the response. But at the same time I potted a header eluding to our custom error page. It wasn't displaying though, and I'd not spotted it as we were getting a successful ajax response.

Digging further into the error logs, I spotted 'Collection is read-only'. Changing the collection Address[] to IList<Address> solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to deduce there was actually a hidden error occurring, even though we were getting a Success response from the Ajax call.

The error was

> Collection is read-only

I changed the address array to an IList:

```
public Address[] OrderAddresses { get; set; }
```

to

```
public IList<Address> OrderAddresses { get; set; }
```

Problem solved!